# REST: Recommendation for format of log data

Tags: json, rest

I have a service that can return log data. Basically, the api is something like `logs?from=1/1/15` and the result is all log lines from the given date.

The problem is that this can be huge data. Assuming the client can download it, if it is in xml/json, then parsing it to a DOM will require large amounts of memory or crash the client. Using SAX or pull parser requires a lot of non trivial code from the client.

The easiest is to have each log line as a json line without line breaks and then the client can break the input by newline and even do it while receiving the data.

Is this a standard way of doing things? What is the mime type here?

Comment: what about to send zipped data?

Comment: that won't help the client to parse

Comment: Why not send the log lines as the are? Why encode them in JSON or XML? Any client that understands log files will be able to handle them line by line.

Comment: my log lines are in json. the 3rd paragraph is to send them line by line. how does this tie with a mime type?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good case for pagination. You have a collection of resources (log lines), and you want a slice of them. Let them specify an offset and a limit and give them that many rows in whatever formats you want to support (json, csv, whatever). This will give clients the flexibility to take as much data as they're comfortable with handling, and it will let you break the lines into reasonable properties (date, message, etc).

I would be very leery of relying on newlines inside JSON to locate record boundaries. Whitespace is explicitly not intended to be used in that fashion.

The MIME type is up to you. If it's JSON, then `application/json` or `application/vnd.whatever+json`.

Comment: @IttayD Yes, it will.